# Edit xml as simple text file in PHP

Tags: php, xml, file, str-replace, implode

I want to replace server's address inside xml file. Placed placeholder `%scr_path%` on line.

```
<property id="urlGenerateImage">%scr_path%/imgcap.php</property>
```

Using following code

```
$path=$wsurl."core/contents/tests";
//read the entire string
$str=implode("\n",file('../includes/ckeditor/plugins/fmath_formula/dialogs/configMathMLEditor.xml'));

$fp=fopen('../includes/ckeditor/plugins/fmath_formula/dialogs/configMathMLEditor.xml','w');
//replace something in the file string 
$str=str_replace('%scr_path%',$path,$str);

//now, TOTALLY rewrite the file
fwrite($fp,$str,strlen($str));
```

Getting bunch of errors about wrong file path. Checked twice path. What's wrong?

Comment: I think you need to provide more detail.  What errors?  Against which line?  How did you check the path?  Can you open the file using php at all?

Comment: No such file or directory. But I'm quite sure that it's path right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends what directory your script is running in. Since you're using a relative path name (../), you'd better be sure you know what directory the script currently is in. Or, even better, set it at the beginning of your script so it will always work.

```
$path = $wsurl."core/contents/tests";

// change directory to project root
chdir("/your/project/directory");

// read the file into a string
$filename = 'includes/ckeditor/plugins/fmath_formula/dialogs/configMathMLEditor.xml';
$str = file_get_contents($filename);

// replace token
$str = str_replace('%scr_path%',$path,$str);

// save file
file_put_contents($filename, $str);
```

Comment: Thx. Chdir helped me. I think it will not extra load server if I'll do it every time on page load, right?